# Error : Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am building a simple to do list in react where I want to store element on submit.I know something is wrong with the handleSubmit() but unable to solve it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function List() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [item, setItem] = useState("");

  function handleSubmit() {
      setItems([ ...items, item ]);
      console.log(items);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>To Do List</h3>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit()}>
        <input
          value={item}
          onChange={(event) => {
            setItem(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <ul>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default List;
```

Comment: Try `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` And you probably want to prevent default there too

Answer (score 1):

`<form onSubmit={handleSubmit()}>` should be `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>`.

By adding `()` you are calling `handleSubmit`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `handleSubmit` function directly instead of passing its reference.
just change `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit()}>` to `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>`

Also you need to preventDefault form submit action. You can add the preventDefault line in your handleSubmit function

```
  function handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      setItems([ ...items, item ]);
      console.log(items);
  }
```